# Python Error: IndexError: list index out of range While Scraping Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm Getting This Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap.py", line 40, in <module>
    phone3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Again And Again

I Notice That when this script click on 3rd button i get this error!

I'm Tried To Fix This Error But I can't fix this error :(

is there any solution to fix this!

and also please tell me why this error i'm getting

Here is the website that i'm trying to scrape

https://www.zameen.com/EstateAgents/Islamabad-3-2.html

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import time

csv = 'islamabad.csv'

with open(csv,'w') as s:
    print('Sheet Maked!: ' + csv)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for i  in range(2,154):
    driver.get('https://www.zameen.com/EstateAgents/Islamabad-3-' + str(i) + '.html')
    name1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[0].text
    name2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[1].text
    name3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[2].text
    name4 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[3].text
    name5 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[4].text
    name6 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[5].text
    name7 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[6].text
    name8 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[7].text
    name9 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[8].text
    name10 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')[9].text
    time.sleep(1)
    button1 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[0].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    #
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button2 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[1].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)   
    button3 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[2].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    print(len(phone3))
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button4 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[3].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone4 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button5 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[4].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone5 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button6 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[5].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone6 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button7 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[6].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone7 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)   
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button8 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[7].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone8 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button9 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[8].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone9 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button10 = driver.find_elements_by_id('agent_phone')[9].click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    phone10 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#mobile')[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
    cross = driver.find_element_by_id('popup_close').click()
    with open(csv,'a') as s:
        for item in range(1):
            s.write(name1 + ',' + phone1 + '\n')
            s.write(name2 + ',' + phone2 + '\n')
            s.write(name3 + ',' + phone3 + '\n')
            s.write(name4 + ',' + phone4 + '\n')
            s.write(name5 + ',' + phone5 + '\n')
            s.write(name6 + ',' + phone6 + '\n')
            s.write(name7 + ',' + phone7 + '\n')
            s.write(name8 + ',' + phone8 + '\n')
            s.write(name9 + ',' + phone9 + '\n')
            s.write(name10 + ',' + phone10 + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace explicit hard coded waits with the selenium wait conditions. There is no need to index if you use find_element_by and also at times the phone number is against a different id so you could use css Or syntax and a list of ids to match against. Go through your code and switch out for these [selenium waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). Perhaps use a function to manage the wait for a given element.

Example wait with CSS Or

```
phone1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , '#mobile, #phone'))).text
```

And imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```